# how to send notification from web-service(microservice) in java to alexa which changes it color to yellow?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

How to send notifications to Alexa using web-service in java . example:if you do submit a user in web-application it should be notified to user by Alexa as notification? How to do it i'm pretty new to this? i have been seeing notifications interface in Alexa i'm not sure how to implement from scratch could you help on this ? can you help me with sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Here is a good blogpost summarizing how it can be done: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/7822f3ee-1735-4eaa-9aa6-5b8e39953c07/proactiveeventsapi-launch-announcement
- and here is the technichal documentation how to do it: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/proactive-events-api.html   - so technically you have to make REST calls out of your java code to amazon backend